# Get all non-full fields in ElasticsearchRepository's findAll method in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using we're using spring-data-elasticsearch 3.2.6.RELEASE and here is our repository :

```
@Repository
public interface IRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

and here is the sample response:

```
[{
        "idDl": null,
        "clientName": null,
        "Address": null
    },
    {
        "idDl": 19810008,
        "clientName": "ABC",
        "Address": "NYC"
        
    }]
```

And we have our own custom implementation to return all values excluding certain fields, as follows: It is exposed as separate REST point.
Here is the interface method

```
public interface IUserService {
    List<User> getFilteredUsers();
}
```

and it's implementation is like :

```
 String[] includeFields = new String[]{"idDl", "clientName"};
 String[] excludeFields = new String[]{"Address"};
 Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                 .withQuery(existsQuery("idDl"))
                 .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(includeFields, excludeFields))
                 .build();
return elasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, User.class);
```

I want to know whether this is interfering with ElasticsearchRepository's `findAll()` method in any way. If not then what is the root cause.

Comment: "what is the root cause." the root cause of what? Where have you implemented this query? How do you call it?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, we have 2 methods, in one method we're calling ElasticsearchRepository's findAll() method and in another method we are calling our filtering implementation as mentioned in above snippet and these two methods are mapped to two different methods of controller, But the response I am getting with findAll() method is as posted in the snippet i.e first object is all null and response I am getting in our custom implementation is proper i.e all null fields object is not in the final response.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, we have written this method in separate class and method having findAll() in another separate class.I just want to know whether this custom field filtering method is interfering with implementation of ElasticsearchRepository's findAll() method. Any suggestions will be really helpful.